# How to add another key to enter command mode?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

In normal mode I have a a lot of `<c-*>` mappings. I end up typing `<c-;>` often when I intended to type `:`. I'd like to add a mapping for `<c-;>` to `:` but nothing I've done works. I've tired:

`nnoremap <c-;> :`

`nnoremap <c-;> gQ`

and about 1/2 a dozen others. No joy. I'm starting to get the "that's not possible" vibe. Which would be kinda sad.
I have other mappings to enter/exit visual mode that just map to `v` I dunno why `:` is special.
I'm on neovim if that matters. (maybe it can be done from lua?)

-Thanks

--- EDIT ---

result of `:verbose map <c-:>` is

```
n  <C-;>       * :
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim line 74
```

line 74 of init.vim is: `nnoremap <C-;> :` If I remove this line then `:verbose map <c-;>` returns`No mapping found`

`

Comment: I'm using Neovm 0.7 and it seems to work fine for me. I suspect that you have a conflict in your mapping. What is the output of `:verbose map <C-;>`?

Comment: it says : 
n  <C-;>       * :                                                                                              
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim line 70

Comment: It seems Ctrl-; is already mapped to `*` online 70. What if you change line 70 to map Ctrl-; to `;`?

Comment: I'm confused. line 70 is my mapping for <c-;> :  if I comment out that line, then run the verbose map it say "No mapping found".
All of my mappings have a * when shown in nmap. What does that mean?

Comment: Could you share your `init.vim` and the output of the `:verbose map <C-;>`?

Comment: the verbose is what is in the comment above. I edited the post to reflect because you can't quote in comments. As a test I removed everyting except the one nnoremap. Same thing. Nothing happens.

Comment: The output of `verbose map <c-;>` is correct. The `*` indicates a non-remappable mapping. (see `:h map-listing`). The final character `:` is the rhs, as expected. The trouble, I suspect, is that not all `<c-xxx>` keys can be mapped. Only `<c-[a-zA-Z]>` can be mapped reliably. See https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5

Comment: But it works for me using Neovim 0.7.0. Can you tell us which version of Neovim you are using. You can get the information using the `:verbose` command.

Comment: I think my terminal isn't passing through "scan codes" or whatever, so vim doesn't see <c-:>. @VivianDeSmedt what terminal/OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows. It works with nvim-qt.exe but it doesn't work with nvim.exe on the console. On the console it seems that `<C-;>` is equivalent to `.` and can be remapped as such.

Comment: The problem is that terminals are essentially based on ASCII and the codes that has and there is no ASCII code for "control-;". Vim only sees what the terminal sends it so you can't really map this. It works in GUIs because GUIs are not restricted to terminals. I made https://bestasciitable.com/ some time ago to explain this issue. You can maybe configure you terminal to send something else on `<C-;>` though (like an escape code), and you can map that in Vim (or just make it send `:`).